# FormData.delete() doesn't work correctly inside a for loop

Tags: javascript

```js
var data = new FormData(document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]);
for(var [key, value] of data.entries()) {
 if (!value) {
    data.delete(key);
    console.log(data.getAll(key));
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="x[1]" type="text" value="">
  <input name="y[2]" type="text" value="">
  <input name="z[3]" type="text" value="">
  <input name="a[4]" type="text" value="">
</form>
```

I have this form and I get its data using `FormData()` then I remove the empty values which is all of them but there is always those random not deleted keys even while it is empty

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Even if you remove the `if` logic and just log the `key` and delete it, only the first and the third keys are deleted. This is pretty weird. Simultaneously deleting and looping the same collection of keys is *probably* causing it to behave this way:

```js
var data = new FormData(document.querySelector("form"));

for(var [key, value] of data.entries()) {
    console.log(key); // only 2 keys get logged
    data.delete(key);
}

console.log(Array.from(data.keys())) // still 2 keys are left
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="x[1]" type="text" value="">
  <input name="y[2]" type="text" value="">
  <input name="z[3]" type="text" value="">
  <input name="a[4]" type="text" value="">
</form>
```

One fix would be to convert the iterator to an array of entries using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). Now when the keys are deleted from `FormData`, the array won't affected:

```js
var data = new FormData(document.querySelector("form"));

for(var [key, value] of Array.from(data.entries())) {
    console.log(key); // every key gets logged now
    data.delete(key);
}

console.log(Array.from(data.keys())) // all are deleted
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="x[1]" type="text" value="">
  <input name="y[2]" type="text" value="">
  <input name="z[3]" type="text" value="">
  <input name="a[4]" type="text" value="">
</form>
```