# Node URLSearchParams delete in loop doesn't delete all entries

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a following object

```
URLSearchParams {
    offset: 'undefined',
    limit: 'undefined',
    types: 'undefined'
}
```

https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_class_urlsearchparams

I want to delete params that are `'undefined'`

```
request.params.forEach((value, name) => {
    if (value == 'undefined' || typeof value == 'undefined') {
        request.params.delete(name);
    }
});
console.log(request.params);
```

I am expecting all three keys should be deleted however when I console log it gives me

```
URLSearchParams { 'limit': 'undefined' }
```

This happens only in loop, if i explicitly delete items, it works fine

```
request.params.delete('offset');
request.params.delete('limit');
request.params.delete('types');
console.log(request.params); // gives `URLSearchParams { }` as expected.
```

Comment: That’s probably due to the fact that you are manipulating the object you are forEach-ing over, from _inside_ the loop body. You removed the first entry `offset`, and now the loop is going, “okay that was the first entry handled, now let’s proceed to the second one” - only that second one is now `types` already, so `limit` gets skipped.

Comment: `URLSearchParams.forEach` seems to be broken in the latest version of Chrome, it skips the first value. [Example](https://jsbin.com/denovayolo/edit?js,console)

Comment: Might be a similar issue to this: [inconsistency from FormData.delete()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57126925). Try with `Array.from(request.params).forEach`

Comment: @Titus not sure that’s relevant here though, when it is a node.js problem.

Comment: @CBroe It is probably broken in Node as well, Chrome is where I've tested.

Comment: Hi, getting this issue in 2023 in latest chrome, but mine keeps 'last' value. My guess is that forEach happens to be doing something possibly promise based, aka a race condition.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to create a new object when deleting fields:

```
data = {
  offset: undefined,
  limit: undefined,
  types: undefined,
  test: 'abc'
}

filtered_data = {}

Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
  let value = data[key]
  if (!(value === 'undefined' || typeof value === 'undefined')) {
    filtered_data[key] = value
  }
})

console.log(filtered_data) // { test: 'abc' }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Adiga

I ended up created copy of this object

```
const params = Array.from(request.params);
for (const element of params) {
    const [key, value] = element;
    if (value == 'undefined' || typeof value == 'undefined') {
        request.params.delete(key);
    }
}
console.log(request.params);
```